# How to access UIScrollview delegates from native ios in nativescript angular?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Iam working the android and ios application using nativescript angular application.i want to access the scrollview delegates of the ios,i was accessed the scrollview delegates from the native ios following code.but it was not working:

My scrollview delegate implementation class:

```
// import {Injectable, EventEmitter,Output} from "@angular/core";
@ObjCClass(UIScrollViewDelegate)
 export class FoodScrollDelegate extends NSObject implements UIScrollViewDelegate
{
    public static ObjCProtocols = [UIScrollViewDelegate];
    // @Output() yvalue:EventEmitter<any>=new EventEmitter();
    private _originalDelegate:UIScrollViewDelegate;
    public getY:Number=0;
     constructor()
     {
         super();
     }

    public static initWithOriginalDelegate(originalDelegate:UIScrollViewDelegate):FoodScrollDelegate{
        console.log("Called Method");
        let delegate=<FoodScrollDelegate>FoodScrollDelegate.new();
        delegate._originalDelegate=originalDelegate;
        return delegate;
    }


}
```

I have setting the scrollview delegate like this:

```
onScrollLoaded(args)
{
    var subscroll=args.object;
    var uiscrollview=subscroll.ios;
    let tf=<any>this.subMenuScroll;
    var newweakref=new WeakRef(uiscrollview);
    const newDelegate=FoodScrollDelegate.initWithOriginalDelegate(tf._delegate);
    console.log("PrintDelegate",+newDelegate);
    uiscrollview.delegate=newDelegate;    

}
```

My MenuComponet class Like this:

```
 import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit,ViewChild, ElementRef} from "@angular/core";
import {Page, borderTopRightRadiusProperty} from "ui/page";
import { isIOS, isAndroid } from 'tns-core-modules/platform';
import { RadListView, ListViewEventData } from "nativescript-ui-listview";
import { RestaurentMenuModel,RestaurentSubMenuModel } from "~/app/models/restaurant";
import { ObservableArray } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable-array";
import { run } from "tns-core-modules/application/application";
import { ScrollEventData, ScrollView } from "tns-core-modules/ui/scroll-view/scroll-view";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { StackLayout } from "tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/stack-layout/stack-layout";
import { Label } from "tns-core-modules/ui/label/label";
import { analyzeAndValidateNgModules } from "@angular/compiler";
import * as utils from "tns-core-modules/utils/utils";
import { setTimeout } from "tns-core-modules/timer";
import { EventData } from "data/observable";
import { FoodScrollDelegate } from "~/app/Utils/scroll_delegate";

declare var UITableViewCellSelectionStyle;
declare var UIView, NSMutableArray, NSIndexPath;

//declare var setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator;



@Component({
    selector:"restaurant_menu",
    moduleId:module.id,
    templateUrl:"./restaurant_menu.component.html",
    styleUrls:["./restaurant_menu.component.css"],
})

export class RestaurantMenu  implements OnInit
{


    //public cartCount:Number=1;
    @ViewChild("ScrollList") scrollList:ElementRef;
    @ViewChild("categoryList") categoryList:ElementRef;
    public AllMenuList:any;
    public cartTotal:any=0;
    public cartItem:any=0;
    public isCartVisible=false;
     incrementItem:any=0;
     decrementItem:any=0;
     categoryContainer:Label;
     subMenuContainers:StackLayout;
     offsetValue:any=0;
     dummyStatus:any=0;
     horizontalOffsetvalue:any=0;
     lengthHorizontaloffsetLength:any=0;   
     public selectedIndex:Number=0;
     public scrollEnabled:Boolean=false;
     lastItemY:Number=0;
     subMenuScroll:ScrollView;
     foodScrollDelegate:FoodScrollDelegate;
    _delegate:any;
    constructor(private page:Page,public routerExtension:RouterExtensions)
    {

    }
    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.subMenuScroll=this.page.getViewById("subMenuScroll");
        //this.subMenuScroll.ios.delegate=FoodScrollDelegate.initWithOriginalDelegate(this._delegate);
       //console.log("PrintDelegate"+this.foodScrollDelegate.scrollViewDidEndDraggingWillDecelerate);
    //    this.foodScrollDelegate=new FoodScrollDelegate();
    //    this.foodScrollDelegate.yvalue.subscribe(yvalue=>{
    //         console.log("TheYYValue"+yvalue);
    //     });


    }
    public scrollViewDidEndDraggingWillDecelerate?(scrollView: UIScrollView, decelerate: boolean): void {
            console.log("WillScrollEnd"+" "+decelerate);
        }
    public scrollViewDidScroll?(scrollView: UIScrollView): void {
            this.getY=scrollView.contentOffset.y;
            console.log("Yposition"+this.getY);
            //this.yvalue.emit(this.getY);
        }
    onLoaded(event)
    {
        const scrollview = event.object;
        if (scrollview.ios) {
            scrollview.ios.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
        }
        else
        {
            scrollview.android.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    onNavBtnTap()
    {
        this.routerExtension.backToPreviousPage();
    }


}
```

Inside the i was implemented the delegate methods.but it was working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObjCClass` is an alternative syntax for `ObjCProtocols`. You may not need to do both.

The default delegate is attached after loaded event, so your delegate may be overwritten again. You will have to extend the ScrollView and override the `attachNative` method.

```
class MyScrollView extends ScrollView {
    protected attachNative() {
        (<any>ScrollView.prototype).attachNative.call(this);
        if (isIOS) {
            (<any>this)._delegate = FoodScrollDelegate.initWithOriginalDelegate((<any>this)._delegate);
            this.nativeViewProtected.delegate = (<any>this)._delegate;
        }
    }
}
```

Register this `MyScrollView`,

```
registerElement("MyScrollView", () => MyScrollView);
```

Now you should be able to use `MyScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` in your HTML which will override the default delegate. If you wanted to override delegate for all ScrollView used in app, you could simply override the prototype chain of `ScrollView` conditionally on iOS.

```
(<any>ScrollView.prototype).originalAttachNative = (<any>ScrollView.prototype).attachNative;
(<any>ScrollView.prototype).attachNative = function () {
    this.originalAttachNative();
    const newDelegate = FoodScrollDelegate.initWithOriginalDelegate(this._delegate);
    this._delegate = newDelegate;
    this.nativeViewProtected.delegate = newDelegate;
};
```

If you like to fire an event from delegate then,

```
   scrollViewDidEndDraggingWillDecelerate(scrollView: UIScrollView, decelerate: boolean) {
        const owner = (<WeakRef<ScrollView>>(<any>this._originalDelegate)._owner).get();
        if (owner) {
            owner.notify({
                object: owner,
                eventName: "dragEnd",
                decelerate: decelerate
            });
        }
    }
```

Now from Angular, you could listen to the event,

**HTML**

```
(dragEnd)="onDragEnd($event)"
```

**TS**

```
onDragEnd(event) {
   console.log(event.decelerate);
}
```

Comment: The delegate methods only working inside the FoodScrollDelegate class.I want the methods working inside html related component class.

Comment: All you would have to do is to fire an event and listen to it from your component.

Comment: Ok i will edit my question what i was called the delegate methods in my component class.

Comment: Hai manoj i was provided my componet class please tell me how to call the delegate methods inside the class?

Comment: As I mentioned above, you may fire an event on ScrollView and listen to the same event form you component.

Comment: Thank you so much Manoj.You saved my day

Comment: In Angular 8, the method name seems to have changed from `attachNative` to `initNativeView`.

Comment: Angular has nothing to do with these methods name. These are the [methods](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/scroll-view/scroll-view.ios.ts#L60) from Core components. And No, the method name is still valid in latest version.